# Variables in other folder are not the same (Python)

Tags: python, import, subdirectory

I have a main folder, with a a main method.

This is the structure:

A main directory

subdirectory A
subdirectory B

Now from the B subdirectory, I would like to access the static variables from a class in A. However, they always end up being 0 (initialization value). When I print from the Main method, the values are correct. When I print from B, the values are incorrect.
I have correctly imported everyting, so the class in directory B *does* recognise classes in A. The only problem seems to be that the class is not correcly included in the total project, and so the variables are instantiated twice, even though the variables are static.

How do I include the classes from subdirectory A in subdirectory B correctly?

I hope anyone can help, been seaching for hours now to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get any response, so my solution was to make a class in my main directory that stores the variables and replace all references to those variables. I guess the way I designed this code was bad practice anyway. It is working now.